# Javascript style issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using javascript to display the height of my current div.

This is an example of the effected area

```
//css
.test
{
height:1px;
}

#test1
{
margin:1px;
}

//html
<div id="test1" class="test"></div>

//javascript
var a = document.getElementById('test1');

a.style.height //how I access the style
```

Firebug says that the length of style is 0 and height is empty.
How can I access the correct height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the computed style, not the specified style.  See [Quirks mode's getstyle](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) page which answers the question

> Sometimes you'll want to see what styles the default document view has. For instance, you gave a paragraph an width of 50%, but how do you see how many pixels that is in your users' browser?

and it explains how to derive and use the `getstyle` function, though it's easier to use a library like jquery which provides a simple [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function.

Comment: Thank you, issue resolved. I used a.style.offsetHeight instead of just a.offsetHeight

Answer (score 2):

Try `a.offsetHeight` instead of `a.style.height`

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eabkh/)

Answer (score 0):

`div` height is dependent on its children. If its empty, it'll be 0.

The code you have to get height is correct, btw.

Comment: Is that issue only to javascript? Its not dependent on them when html display the div.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) method. It should do what you are looking for. Kinda lame, really, I wish this was handled better in the DOM.